# How Can I Get CurrentWindow?

Tags: c#

yes i want to get a child window of another application.
 Give me Sum Idea or code

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do. Do you want to get the top level window of your application or another application? Or do you want to get a child window? If yes, which child do you want to get (as there are usually way more than one)? And how is the child window specified? By its class name?

Comment: yes i want to get a child window of another application.
Give me Sum Idea or code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve the handle to a window given its title:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("window found");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No window with given title has been found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sarvesh: In your comment you stated that you want to retrieve a child window. But be aware that the example above gives you the handle to another application's *top-level* window. To get a better understanding about the differences you might want to play around a bit with Spy++.